# Understanding rust borrowing and dereferencing

Tags: rust

I was reading through the Rust documentation and can't quite seem to be able to wrap my head around what is going on. For example, over [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow.html) I see the following example:

```rust
// This function takes ownership of a box and destroys it
fn eat_box_i32(boxed_i32: Box<i32>) {
    println!("Destroying box that contains {}", boxed_i32);
}

// This function borrows an i32
fn borrow_i32(borrowed_i32: &i32) {
    println!("This int is: {}", borrowed_i32);
}

fn main() {
    // Create a boxed i32, and a stacked i32
    let boxed_i32 = Box::new(5_i32);
    let stacked_i32 = 6_i32;

    // Borrow the contents of the box. Ownership is not taken,
    // so the contents can be borrowed again.
    borrow_i32(&boxed_i32);
    borrow_i32(&stacked_i32);

    {
        // Take a reference to the data contained inside the box
        let _ref_to_i32: &i32 = &boxed_i32;

        // Error!
        // Can't destroy `boxed_i32` while the inner value is borrowed later in scope.
        eat_box_i32(boxed_i32);
        // FIXME ^ Comment out this line

        // Attempt to borrow `_ref_to_i32` after inner value is destroyed
        borrow_i32(_ref_to_i32);
        // `_ref_to_i32` goes out of scope and is no longer borrowed.
    }

    // `boxed_i32` can now give up ownership to `eat_box` and be destroyed
    eat_box_i32(boxed_i32);
}
```

Things I believe:

1. eat_box_i32 takes a pointer to a Box
2. this line `let boxed_i32 = Box::new(5_i32);` makes is so that boxed_i32 now contains a pointer because Box is not a primitive

Things I don't understand:

1. why do we need to call `borrow_i32(&boxed_i32);` with the ampersand? Isn't boxed_i32 already a pointer?
2. on this line: `let _ref_to_i32: &i32 = &boxed_i32;` why is the ampersand required on the right hand side? Isn't boxed_i32 already an address?
3. how come borrow_i32 can be called with pointer to Box and pointer to i32 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Comment on the term "pointers"

You can skip this part if you'd like, I just figured given the questions you asked, this might be a helpful comment:

In Rust, `&i32`, `&mut i32`, `*const i32`, `*mut i32`, `Box<i32>`, `Rc<i32>`, `Arc<i32>` are all arguably a "pointer to `i32`" type. However, Rust will not let you convert between them casually, even between those that are laid out identically in memory.

It can be useful to talk about pointers in general sometimes, but as a rule of thumb, if you're trying to figure out why one piece of Rust code compiles, and another doesn't, I'd recommend keeping track of which kind of pointer you're working with.

---

#### Things you believe:

> 1. eat_box_i32 takes a pointer to a Box

Actually not quite. `eat_box_i32` accepts a `Box<i32>`, and not a pointer to a `Box<i32>`. It just so happens that `Box<i32>` in memory is stored as a pointer to an `i32`.

> 2. this line let boxed_i32 = Box::new(5_i32); makes is so that boxed_i32 now contains a pointer because Box is not a primitive

Yes, `boxed_i32` is a pointer.

---

#### Things you don't understand:

> 1. why do we need to call borrow_i32(&boxed_i32); with the ampersand? Isn't boxed_i32 already a pointer?

Yes, `boxed_i32` is already a pointer. However, a boxed pointer still indicates ownership. If you passed `boxed_i32` instead of `&boxed_i32`, you would still be passing a pointer, but Rust will consider that variable "consumed", and you would no longer be able to use `boxed_i32` after that function call.

> 2. on this line: let _ref_to_i32: &i32 = &boxed_i32; why is the ampersand required on the right hand side? Isn't boxed_i32 already an address?

Yes, `boxed_i32` is already an address, but the fact that it's an address is kind of meant to be opaque (like a `struct` with a single private field). The actual type of `&boxed_i32` is `&Box<i32>`.

Though this is weird right? If `&boxed_i32` is `&Box<i32>`, how can you assign it to a variable of type `&i32`?

This is actually a shorthand -- If a type `T` implements the `Deref<Target=R>` trait, it'll automatically convert values of type `&T` into values of type `&R` as needed. And it turns out that the `Box<T>` type implements `Deref<Target=T>`.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html for more info about `Deref`.

So if you wrote it out explicitly without that automatic conversion, that line would actually look something like:

```
let _ref_to_i32: &i32 = Deref::deref(&boxed_i32);
```

> 3. how come borrow_i32 can be called with pointer to Box and pointer to i32 ?

The reason is the same as with (2) above.

`borrow_i32` accepts `&i32` as its parameter. Passing `&i32` is obviously ok because the types match exactly. If you try to pass it `&Box<i32>`, Rust will automatically convert it to `&i32` for you, because `Box<i32>` implements `Deref<i32>`.

---

EDIT: Thanks @kmdreko for pointing out that `Deref` allows the coercion, and not `AsRef`

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement @math4tots, the auto dereferencing is call Deref Coercion.  It is explained in the rustbook here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods